# Nested Grouped ListView in XAML

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm making a chatting app like WhatsApp. This is the layout I want to make,

- `Me`(Static HeaderText)

  - MyInformation(Profile Image and name)
- `Favorites`(Static HeaderText)

  - My Favorite friend information(Profile Image and name)
  - My Favorite friend
- `Friends`(Static HeaderText)

  - `A`

    - My friend information(His name starts with A)
    - My friend
  - `B`

    - My friend

I implemented this with `3 listviews`(Me, favorites, friends) in the `Grid`.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="CollectionGroupedView" IsSourceGrouped="True" ItemsPath="Members" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="MeView" SelectionMode="None"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StandardTripleLineItemTemplate}"
        Header="Me"
        >
    </ListView>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="FavoriteView" SelectionMode="None"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StandardTripleLineItemTemplate}"
                Header="Favorite"
                >
    </ListView>
    <ListView Grid.Row="2" x:Name="FriendListView" SelectionMode="None"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionGroupedView}}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StandardTripleLineItemTemplate}"
                        Header="Friends"
                        >
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And this is the result.
[image]

But as you can see, it doesn't work what I expected first.

The first problem is, `each listview` has its own `ScrollView`.
I need **one outer scrollview**. To solve this problem I tried to use `StackPanel` in the outside of listviews. But then scrollview has gone.

The second one is, when I scroll down the `third listview`, the header text `Friends` also scrolled. It shouldn't be.

If I can use nested `CollectionViewSource`, it might be possible. But I think there is no interfact like that.
How should I do layout this structure? Any experience or idea?

P.S Target Platform is Windows Phone 8.1. But I screen-captured it on WinRT application to show you the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

1- for the whole scroll, one thought is that you can add your main grid in scrollview control in that case all the page will have one scroll.

here is how.

```
<ScrollViewer>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Grid.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="CollectionGroupedView" IsSourceGrouped="True" ItemsPath="Members" />
</Grid.Resources>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="MeView" SelectionMode="None"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StandardTripleLineItemTemplate}"
    Header="Me"
    >
</ListView> ....  </Grid></ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/
It has a control called TreeView. Maybe that will help!